# How to (is it possible to) call yield inside of closure in F#?

Tags: f#, closures, sequence, yield

I am trying to write a function, which takes sequence of strings and returns the sequence of strings all prefixed by given another string with the help of Seq.iter, but can't deduce correct syntax.

```
//let concatElemSeq (elem : string) (s : seq<string>) : seq<string> = (Seq.map (fun it -> elem+it) s)

let concatElemSeq (elem : string) (s : seq<string>) : seq<string> = seq {
    Seq.iter (fun it -> 
        yield elem+it
        ()
    ) s
}
```

How to accomplish?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it is not possible to nest `yield` like that. `yield` has to be part of the computation expression syntax.

To achieve what you want, use `for`:

```
let concatElemSeq (elem : string) (s : seq<string>) : seq<string> = seq { 
    for it in s do
        yield elem+it
}
```

Or even shorter, using `->` as a shortcut for `do yield`:

```
let concatElemSeq (elem : string) (s : seq<string>) : seq<string> = seq { 
    for it in s -> elem+it
}
```

Alternatively, you can do this with `Seq.map` and partially applied `(+)`:

```
let concatElemSeq elem s = Seq.map ((+) elem) s
```

And then eta-reduce:

```
let concatElemSeq elem = Seq.map ((+) elem)
```